# Error: Unknown symbol in module?

Tags: c, kernel-module, insmod

I wrote a simple Linux kernel module:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/reboot.h>

static int my_init(void)
{
    machine_power_off();
    return  0;
}

static void my_exit(void)
{
    return;
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);
```

Source compiled successfully but after installing the module (`insmod`) the following error occurred:

```
Error: could not insert module my_module.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

System log error:

```
Jun 25 21:50:00 my-virtual-machine kernel: [31625.207827] my_module: Unknown symbol machine_power_off (err 0)
```

How do I solve this error?

machine_power_off:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=machine_power_off

Comment: It seems, `machine_power_off()` is not exported by the kernel.

Comment: Of all the drivers, only windfarm* drivers for Macintosh seem to use it but I am not sure how they manage to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Amir, traversed through the files in the linux kernel, w.r.t. all the architecture files where **machine_power_off()** is used, it is not exported so cannot be used in your module.